# Understanding complex toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am new to Jquery and basically i came across the following peice of code , its basically a accordion that makes use of localstorage.

```
$(function () {
    var initialCollapse = localStorage.collapse;


    if (initialCollapse) initialCollapse = initialCollapse.split(",")
    console.log(initialCollapse);
    $(".collapse-headings>a").click(function () {
        var div = $(this).parent();

        div.toggleClass("close open");


        $(".collapse-content", div).toggle("slow");

        localStorage.collapse = $(".collapse-headings").map(function () {
            return $(this).hasClass("open") ? "open" : "close"
        }).get()

        console.log(localStorage.collapse)
        return false;
    })
    if (initialCollapse) {
        $(".collapse-headings>a").each(function (i) {
            var div = $(this).parent();
            div.removeClass("close open").addClass(initialCollapse[i])

            $(".collapse-content", div).toggle(initialCollapse[i] !== "close");

        })
    }

});
```

**[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/a49kc6ha/1/)**.

now i went throught the JQuery doc's and it was quite helpful and basically i was able to understand most of the code except one line of code , I.E.

```
$(".collapse-content", div).toggle(initialCollapse[i] !== "close");
```

what if the above line of code doing ?? i understand that it is using the not equal to operator , but how exactly is it functioning ? can somebody explain ? please break it down for me as i am a JS newbie .

Thank you.

gautam.

Comment: Toggle accepts a boolean to define wether to show or hide an element, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display). So the expression `initialCollapse[i] !== "close"` will return `true` or `false`. Little example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/81j08nkg/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the complexity of the boolean check for a moment, would it make more sense if it was

```
$(".collapse-content", div).toggle(true);
```

or

```
$(".collapse-content", div).toggle(false);
```

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) say

> Use true to show the element or false to hide it.

So the boolean check `initialCollapse[i] !== "close"` will be `true` if that particular element of the accordion is not set to "close".

Answer (score 2):

To break it down (even more):

```
$(".collapse-content", div).toggle(initialCollapse[i] !== "close");
```

`.collapse-content` is the class selector, as I'm sure you know. The second parameter, `div`, is the scope/context for the selector (the selector will only be searched for within the scope of this). In this case `div` is just variable that is set to `$(this).parent();` (referenced within a each loop. So *this* is the current element in that loop).

The statement `initialCollapse[i] !== "close"` will return either `true` or `false`, depending if the value of the current array position equals *'close'* or not (in this case it will return `true` if the value of the array is **not** 'close').

As for the array `initialCollapse`, it is set at the top:

```
var initialCollapse = localStorage.collapse;
if (initialCollapse) initialCollapse = initialCollapse.split(",")
```

Set to `localStorage.collapse` and then, if it has any data, split in to an array by commas.

So, simplifying it this will be interpreted like:

```
//I'm typing out the scope/context explicitly for illustration
$(".collapse-content", ".collapse-headings>a").toggle(true); //or false
```

True will toggle the element to *show*, and *false* to hide.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it's where it sets the all the initial values, locally stored.

It will loop all the elements `$(".collapse-headings>a").each(...` and show or hide the element based on the `localStorage` value `"open"` or `"close"`.

*toggle* accepts a Boolean, `true` to show, `false` to hide the element ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display))

If the stored value is `"close"`, it should pass `false` to *toogle* function, so  `initialCollapse[i] !== "close"` returns a false.

For instance: `initialCollapse[i] === "open"` would also works.

---

**Note:**
A nice way to simplify that code is to change this two lines:

```
return $(this).hasClass("open") ? "open" : "close"
...
$(".collapse-content", div).toggle(initialCollapse[i] !== "close");
```

to this:

```
return $(this).hasClass("open")
...
$(".collapse-content", div).toggle(initialCollapse[i]);
```

You would be storing a Boolean instead of a string, which would be lighter and it would simplify the comparison.